# UnivariateSpline equivalent for exponential functions?

Tags: python, numpy, spline, exponential

I currently have a set of data that I wish to make a function out of that is defined for all values of possible values of `temp_vp` (my x data in this case)

```
temp_vp = [280.0,290.0,300.0,310.0,320.0,330.0,340.0,350.0,360.0,370.0,380.0,390.0,400.0,410.0,420.0,430.0,440.0,450.0,460.0,470.0,480.0,490.0,500.0]
vp_in = [3.88e-52,5.16e-50,4.95e-48,3.53e-46,1.93e-44,8.26e-43,2.83e-41,7.93e-40,1.85e-38,3.62e-37,6.07e-36,8.79e-35,1.11e-33,1.25e-32,1.24e-31,1.11e-30,9.03e-30,6.66e-29,4.51e-28,2.81e-27,1.62e-26,8.72e-26,4.38e-25]
```

I have used `UnivariateSpline` before in order to interpolate between data points and give a constant values outside of the given data range. However, when I try and use it this time for this data, I get this:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get a desired interpolated function for this data, to the requirements described previously?

My current code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy import interp
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp_vp = [280.0,290.0,300.0,310.0,320.0,330.0,340.0,350.0,360.0,370.0,380.0,390.0,400.0,410.0,420.0,430.0,440.0,450.0,460.0,470.0,480.0,490.0,500.0]
vp_in = [3.88e-52,5.16e-50,4.95e-48,3.53e-46,1.93e-44,8.26e-43,2.83e-41,7.93e-40,1.85e-38,3.62e-37,6.07e-36,8.79e-35,1.11e-33,1.25e-32,1.24e-31,1.11e-30,9.03e-30,6.66e-29,4.51e-28,2.81e-27,1.62e-26,8.72e-26,4.38e-25]

tempspace = np.linspace(200,10000,10000)
vp_f = UnivariateSpline(temp_vp, vp_in, k = 1, ext = 3)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,3.6))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.minorticks_on() # enable minor ticks
ax.set_axisbelow(True) # put grid behind curves
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4, alpha = 0.12) # turn on major grid
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='black', linestyle='-', zorder=1, linewidth=0.4, alpha = 0.12) # turn on minor grid
ax.scatter(temp_vp,vp_in, color = 'black', label = 'data', s= 5, zorder = 3)
ax.plot(tempspace, vp_f(tempspace), color = 'blue', label = 'Fit', zorder = 2)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature [K]')
ax.set_ylabel('Vapor Pressure [Pa]')
ax.legend(labelspacing=0.25, fontsize = 8)
plt.xlim([250,600])
#plt.ylim([1e-10,1e5])
plt.savefig('Al_vpdata.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf')
plt.savefig('Al_vpdata.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really measuring pressures of 1e-50 Pa?

You are probably having underflow errors.

If you multiply `vp_in` by 1e52 you get:

[image]

Comment: Yes I really am measuring values of 1e-50 so multiplying the data isn't really an option, unless I shift everything back down after the fit has been found